# Auto-increment based on two columns in Sequelize for postgres

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to store student datas as follows in postgres,
where roll number should auto increment based on the batch.

I want to know how to implement this in Sequelize.

```
id       batch         rollno      name
---------------------------------------------------------------
1         A             1000        John
2         A             1001        Javed
3         A             1002        Jake
4         B             1000        Jose
5         B             1001        James
6         A             1003        Jerry
```

Here is the model I created.

```
var Student = sequelize.define('student', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    batch: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    rollno: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with a regular auto increment because that would require a different sequence for each batch. You could do it by writing a trigger that fires on insert and that queries the table for the current maximum rollno in the batch and adds 1, but it's probably a bad idea.

What you can do instead is to calculate the rollno when you run a query:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id serial,
  batch text
);

INSERT INTO test (batch) VALUES ('A');

SELECT
  id,
  batch,
  999 + rank() OVER (PARTITION BY batch order by id) as rollno
FROM test
order by id
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vbVpvhfpzuhxKqQfNWsQVc/0